# Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value

Tags: r, data.table, zoo, r-faq

In a `data.frame` (or `data.table`), I would like to "fill forward" NAs with the closest previous non-NA value. A simple example, using vectors (instead of a `data.frame`) is the following:

```
> y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)
```

I would like a function `fill.NAs()` that allows me to construct `yy` such that:

```
> yy
[1] NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4
```

I need to repeat this operation for many (total ~1 Tb) small sized `data.frame`s (~30-50 Mb), where a row is NA is all its entries are. What is a good way to approach the problem?

The ugly solution I cooked up uses this function:

```
last <- function (x){
    x[length(x)]
}    

fill.NAs <- function(isNA){
if (isNA[1] == 1) {
    isNA[1:max({which(isNA==0)[1]-1},1)] <- 0 # first is NAs 
                                              # can't be forward filled
}
isNA.neg <- isNA.pos <- isNA.diff <- diff(isNA)
isNA.pos[isNA.diff < 0] <- 0
isNA.neg[isNA.diff > 0] <- 0
which.isNA.neg <- which(as.logical(isNA.neg))
if (length(which.isNA.neg)==0) return(NULL) # generates warnings later, but works
which.isNA.pos <- which(as.logical(isNA.pos))
which.isNA <- which(as.logical(isNA))
if (length(which.isNA.neg)==length(which.isNA.pos)){
    replacement <- rep(which.isNA.pos[2:length(which.isNA.neg)], 
                                which.isNA.neg[2:max(length(which.isNA.neg)-1,2)] - 
                                which.isNA.pos[1:max(length(which.isNA.neg)-1,1)])      
    replacement <- c(replacement, rep(last(which.isNA.pos), last(which.isNA) - last(which.isNA.pos)))
} else {
    replacement <- rep(which.isNA.pos[1:length(which.isNA.neg)], which.isNA.neg - which.isNA.pos[1:length(which.isNA.neg)])     
    replacement <- c(replacement, rep(last(which.isNA.pos), last(which.isNA) - last(which.isNA.pos)))
}
replacement
}
```

The function `fill.NAs` is used as follows:

```
y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)
isNA <- as.numeric(is.na(y))
replacement <- fill.NAs(isNA)
if (length(replacement)){
which.isNA <- which(as.logical(isNA))
to.replace <- which.isNA[which(isNA==0)[1]:length(which.isNA)]
y[to.replace] <- y[replacement]
}
```

***Output***

```
> y
[1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4
```

... which seems to work. But, man, is it ugly! Any suggestions?

Comment: From other questions since this one, I think you've now found `roll=TRUE` in `data.table`.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You probably want to use the `na.locf()` function from the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) package to *carry the last observation forward* to replace your NA values.

Here is the beginning of its usage example from the help page:

```
library(zoo)

az <- zoo(1:6)

bz <- zoo(c(2,NA,1,4,5,2))

na.locf(bz)
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 2 1 4 5 2 

na.locf(bz, fromLast = TRUE)
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 1 1 4 5 2 

cz <- zoo(c(NA,9,3,2,3,2))

na.locf(cz)
2 3 4 5 6 
9 3 2 3 2
```

Comment: Also note that `na.locf` in zoo works with ordinary vectors as well as zoo objects.  Its `na.rm` argument can be useful in some applications.

Comment: Use `na.locf(cz, na.rm=FALSE)` to keep leading `NA`.

Comment: @BallpointBen 's  comment is important and should be included in the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

Sorry for digging up an old question. 
I couldn't look up the function to do this job on the train, so I wrote one myself.

I was proud to find out that it's a tiny bit faster.
It's less flexible though.

But it plays nice with `ave`, which is what I needed.

```
repeat.before = function(x) {   # repeats the last non NA value. Keeps leading NA
    ind = which(!is.na(x))      # get positions of nonmissing values
    if(is.na(x[1]))             # if it begins with a missing, add the 
          ind = c(1,ind)        # first position to the indices
    rep(x[ind], times = diff(   # repeat the values at these indices
       c(ind, length(x) + 1) )) # diffing the indices + length yields how often 
}                               # they need to be repeated

x = c(NA,NA,'a',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'b','c','d',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'e')  
xx = rep(x, 1000000)  
system.time({ yzoo = na.locf(xx,na.rm=F)})  
## user  system elapsed   
## 2.754   0.667   3.406   
system.time({ yrep = repeat.before(xx)})  
## user  system elapsed   
## 0.597   0.199   0.793
```

### Edit

As this became my most upvoted answer, I was reminded often that I don't use my own function, because I often need zoo's `maxgap` argument. Because zoo has some weird problems in edge cases when I use dplyr + dates that I couldn't debug, I came back to this today to improve my old function.

I benchmarked my improved function and all the other entries here. For the basic set of features, `tidyr::fill` is fastest while also not failing the edge cases. The Rcpp entry by @BrandonBertelsen is faster still, but it's inflexible regarding the input's type (he tested edge cases incorrectly due to a misunderstanding of `all.equal`).

If you need `maxgap`, my function below is faster than zoo (and doesn't have the weird problems with dates).

I put up the [documentation of my tests](http://rpubs.com/rubenarslan/repeat_last_na_locf).

#### new function

```
repeat_last = function(x, forward = TRUE, maxgap = Inf, na.rm = FALSE) {
    if (!forward) x = rev(x)           # reverse x twice if carrying backward
    ind = which(!is.na(x))             # get positions of nonmissing values
    if (is.na(x[1]) && !na.rm)         # if it begins with NA
        ind = c(1,ind)                 # add first pos
    rep_times = diff(                  # diffing the indices + length yields how often
        c(ind, length(x) + 1) )          # they need to be repeated
    if (maxgap < Inf) {
        exceed = rep_times - 1 > maxgap  # exceeding maxgap
        if (any(exceed)) {               # any exceed?
            ind = sort(c(ind[exceed] + 1, ind))      # add NA in gaps
            rep_times = diff(c(ind, length(x) + 1) ) # diff again
        }
    }
    x = rep(x[ind], times = rep_times) # repeat the values at these indices
    if (!forward) x = rev(x)           # second reversion
    x
}
```

I've also put the function in my [formr package](https://github.com/rubenarslan/formr) (Github only).

Answer (score 48):

a `data.table` solution:

```
dt <- data.table(y = c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA))
dt[, y_forward_fill := y[1], .(cumsum(!is.na(y)))]
dt
     y y_forward_fill
 1: NA             NA
 2:  2              2
 3:  2              2
 4: NA              2
 5: NA              2
 6:  3              3
 7: NA              3
 8:  4              4
 9: NA              4
10: NA              4
```

this approach could work with forward filling zeros as well:

```
dt <- data.table(y = c(0, 2, -2, 0, 0, 3, 0, -4, 0, 0))
dt[, y_forward_fill := y[1], .(cumsum(y != 0))]
dt
     y y_forward_fill
 1:  0              0
 2:  2              2
 3: -2             -2
 4:  0             -2
 5:  0             -2
 6:  3              3
 7:  0              3
 8: -4             -4
 9:  0             -4
10:  0             -4
```

this method becomes very useful on data at scale and where you would want to perform a forward fill by group(s), which is trivial with `data.table`. just add the group(s) to the `by` clause prior to the `cumsum` logic.

```
dt <- data.table(group = sample(c('a', 'b'), 20, replace = TRUE), y = sample(c(1:4, rep(NA, 4)), 20 , replace = TRUE))
dt <- dt[order(group)]
dt[, y_forward_fill := y[1], .(group, cumsum(!is.na(y)))]
dt
    group  y y_forward_fill
 1:     a NA             NA
 2:     a NA             NA
 3:     a NA             NA
 4:     a  2              2
 5:     a NA              2
 6:     a  1              1
 7:     a NA              1
 8:     a  3              3
 9:     a NA              3
10:     a NA              3
11:     a  4              4
12:     a NA              4
13:     a  1              1
14:     a  4              4
15:     a NA              4
16:     a  3              3
17:     b  4              4
18:     b NA              4
19:     b NA              4
20:     b  2              2
```

Comment: I'm familiar with tidyverse but new to data.table - can I ask you what this does?

dt[, y_forward_fill := y[1], .(cumsum(!is.na(y)))]

Specifically, y[1] and why .(cumsum(!is.na(y))) forward fills the NAs?

Comment: HI @TonyDiFranco, how would you suggest someone implement this if the intention is to fill backwards?

Comment: @JantjeHouten the simplest, though not most efficient, approach would be to reverse the sort order of the data.table, perform a forward fill as indicated, and then reverse once more back to the original order

Answer (score 40):

The `tidyr` package (part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages) has a simple way to do that:

```
y = c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)

# first, transform it into a data.frame

df = as.data.frame(y)
   y
1  NA
2   2
3   2
4  NA
5  NA
6   3
7  NA
8   4
9  NA
10 NA

library(tidyr)
fill(df, y, .direction = 'down')
    y
1  NA
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   4
9   4
10  4
```

Comment: The downside of this function is that, first the atomic vector has to be created `as.data.frame()` and that the output is also a `data.frame` instead of atomic vector

Comment: @AnilGoyal It's an upside for my case

Comment: This is by far and away the simplest and best answer for this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

You can use the `data.table` function `nafill`, available from `data.table >= 1.12.3`.

```
library(data.table)
nafill(y, type = "locf")
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

If your vector is a column in a `data.table`, you can also update it by reference with `setnafill`:

```
d <- data.table(x = 1:10, y)
setnafill(d, type = "locf", cols = "y")
d
#      x  y
#  1:  1 NA
#  2:  2  2
#  3:  3  2
#  4:  4  2
#  5:  5  2
#  6:  6  3
#  7:  7  3
#  8:  8  4
#  9:  9  4
# 10: 10  4
```

---

If you have `NA` in several columns...

```
d <- data.table(x = c(1, NA, 2), y = c(2, 3, NA), z = c(4, NA, 5))
#     x  y  z
# 1:  1  2  4
# 2: NA  3 NA
# 3:  2 NA  5
```

...you can fill them by reference in one go:

```
setnafill(d, type = "locf")
d
#    x y z
# 1: 1 2 4
# 2: 1 3 4
# 3: 2 3 5
```

---

Note that:

> Only *double* and *integer* data types are currently [`data.table 1.12.6`]
>   supported.

The functionality will most likely soon be extended; see the open issue [nafill, setnafill for character, factor and other types](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3992), where you also find a [temporary workaround](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3992#issuecomment-546295277).

Answer (score 25):

Throwing my hat in:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('IntegerVector na_locf(IntegerVector x) {
  int n = x.size();

  for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if((i > 0) && (x[i] == NA_INTEGER) & (x[i-1] != NA_INTEGER)) {
      x[i] = x[i-1];
    }
  }
  return x;
}')
```

Setup a basic sample and a benchmark:

```
x <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,NA))

bench_em <- function(x,count = 10) {
  x <- sample(x,count,replace = TRUE)
  print(microbenchmark(
    na_locf(x),
    replace_na_with_last(x),
    na.lomf(x),
    na.locf(x),
    repeat.before(x)
  ), order = "mean", digits = 1)
}
```

And run some benchmarks:

```
bench_em(x,1e6)

Unit: microseconds
                    expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval
              na_locf(x)   697   798   821    814   821 1e+03   100
              na.lomf(x)  3511  4137  5002   4214  4330 1e+04   100
 replace_na_with_last(x)  4482  5224  6473   5342  5801 2e+04   100
        repeat.before(x)  4793  5044  6622   5097  5520 1e+04   100
              na.locf(x) 12017 12658 17076  13545 19193 2e+05   100
```

Just in case:

```
all.equal(
     na_locf(x),
     replace_na_with_last(x),
     na.lomf(x),
     na.locf(x),
     repeat.before(x)
)
[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

For a numeric vector, the function is a bit different:

```
NumericVector na_locf_numeric(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  LogicalVector ina = is_na(x);

  for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
    if((ina[i] == TRUE) & (ina[i-1] != TRUE)) {
      x[i] = x[i-1];
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Dealing with a big data volume, in order to be more efficient, we can use the data.table package.

```
require(data.table)
replaceNaWithLatest <- function(
  dfIn,
  nameColNa = names(dfIn)[1]
){
  dtTest <- data.table(dfIn)
  setnames(dtTest, nameColNa, "colNa")
  dtTest[, segment := cumsum(!is.na(colNa))]
  dtTest[, colNa := colNa[1], by = "segment"]
  dtTest[, segment := NULL]
  setnames(dtTest, "colNa", nameColNa)
  return(dtTest)
}
```

Comment: An lapply can be added so it can directly apply it to multiple NA columns:
`replaceNaWithLatest <- function(
      dfIn,
      nameColsNa = names(dfIn)[1]
    ){
      dtTest <- data.table(dfIn)
      invisible(lapply(nameColsNa, function(nameColNa){
        setnames(dtTest, nameColNa, "colNa")
        dtTest[, segment := cumsum(!is.na(colNa))]
        dtTest[, colNa := colNa[1], by = "segment"]
        dtTest[, segment := NULL]
        setnames(dtTest, "colNa", nameColNa)
      }))
      return(dtTest)
    }`

Comment: At first I was excited by this solution, but it's actually not doing the same thing at all. The question is about filling in 1 data set with another. This answer is just imputation.

Answer (score 20):

This has worked for me:

```
  replace_na_with_last<-function(x,a=!is.na(x)){
     x[which(a)[c(1,1:sum(a))][cumsum(a)+1]]
  }


> replace_na_with_last(c(1,NA,NA,NA,3,4,5,NA,5,5,5,NA,NA,NA))

[1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

> replace_na_with_last(c(NA,"aa",NA,"ccc",NA))

[1] "aa"  "aa"  "aa"  "ccc" "ccc"
```

speed is reasonable too:

```
> system.time(replace_na_with_last(sample(c(1,2,3,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE)))


 user  system elapsed 

 0.072   0.000   0.071
```

Comment: This function doesn't do what you expect when there are leading NAs. `replace_na_with_last(c(NA,1:4,NA))` (i.e. they're filled with the following value). This is also the default behaviour of `imputeTS::na.locf(x, na.remaining = "rev")`.

Comment: better to add a default for this case, slightly different approach:

``replace_na_with_last<-function(x,p=is.na,d=0)c(d,x)[cummax(seq_along(x)*(!p(x)))+1]``

Comment: @NickNassuphis 's answer is short, sweet, not package-dependent, and works well with dplyr pipes!

Answer (score 18):

Having a leading `NA` is a bit of a wrinkle, but I find a very readable (and vectorized) way of doing LOCF when the leading term is *not* missing is:

`na.omit(y)[cumsum(!is.na(y))]`

A slightly less readable modification works in general:

`c(NA, na.omit(y))[cumsum(!is.na(y))+1]`

gives the desired output:

`c(NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)`

Answer (score 17):

Try this function. It does not require the ZOO package:

```
# last observation moved forward
# replaces all NA values with last non-NA values
na.lomf <- function(x) {

    na.lomf.0 <- function(x) {
        non.na.idx <- which(!is.na(x))
        if (is.na(x[1L])) {
            non.na.idx <- c(1L, non.na.idx)
        }
        rep.int(x[non.na.idx], diff(c(non.na.idx, length(x) + 1L)))
    }

    dim.len <- length(dim(x))

    if (dim.len == 0L) {
        na.lomf.0(x)
    } else {
        apply(x, dim.len, na.lomf.0)
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
> # vector
> na.lomf(c(1, NA,2, NA, NA))
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
> 
> # matrix
> na.lomf(matrix(c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA), ncol = 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
```

Comment: To improve it you can add this: `if (!anyNA(x)) return(x)`.

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of packages offering `na.locf` (`NA` Last Observation Carried Forward) functions:

- `xts` - `xts::na.locf`
- `zoo` - `zoo::na.locf`
- `imputeTS` -  `imputeTS::na.locf`
- `spacetime` - `spacetime::na.locf`

And also other packages where this function is named differently.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Brandon Bertelsen's Rcpp contributions. For me, the NumericVector version didn't work: it only replaced the first NA. This is because the `ina` vector is only evaluated once, at the beginning of the function.

Instead, one can take the exact same approach as for the IntegerVector function. The following worked for me:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector na_locf_numeric(NumericVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.size();
  for(R_xlen_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if(i > 0 && !R_finite(x[i]) && R_finite(x[i-1])) {
      x[i] = x[i-1];
    }
  }
  return x;
}')
```

In case you need a CharacterVector version, the same basic approach also works:

```
cppFunction('CharacterVector na_locf_character(CharacterVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.size();
  for(R_xlen_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if(i > 0 && x[i] == NA_STRING && x[i-1] != NA_STRING) {
      x[i] = x[i-1];
    }
  }
  return x;
}')
```

Comment: int n = x.size() and for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) should be replaced by double. In R an vector can be larger than c++ int size.

Comment: It looks like this function returns "R_xlen_t". If R is compiled with long vector support, this is defined as ptrdiff_t; if it isn't, it's an int. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modification of @AdamO's solution. This one runs faster, because it bypasses the `na.omit` function. This will overwrite the `NA` values in vector `y` (except for leading `NA`s).

```
   z  <- !is.na(y)                  # indicates the positions of y whose values we do not want to overwrite
   z  <- z | !cumsum(z)             # for leading NA's in y, z will be TRUE, otherwise it will be FALSE where y has a NA and TRUE where y does not have a NA
   y  <- y[z][cumsum(z)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add a next solution which using the `runner` r cran package.

```r
library(runner)
y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)
fill_run(y, FALSE)
 [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

The whole package is optimized and major of it was written in cpp. Thus offer a great efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

An option in *base*, derive from the answers of @Montgomery-Clift and @AdamO, *replacing `NA`'s with latest non-`NA` value* could be:

```
y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)

i <- c(TRUE, !is.na(y[-1]))
y[i][cumsum(i)]
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

When only a few `NA` exist they could be overwritten with the values of the *latest non-NA value* instead of creating a new vector.

```
fillNaR <- function(y) {
  i <- which(is.na(y[-1]))
  j <- which(diff(c(-1L,i)) > 1)
  k <- diff(c(j, length(i) + 1))
  i <- rep(i[j], k)
  `[<-`(y, i + sequence(k), y[i])
}
fillNaR(y)
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

When speed is important a loop propagating the last non-NA value in a loop could be written using RCPP. To be flexible on the input type this can be done using a template.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> FNA(const Vector<RTYPE> y) {
  auto x = clone(y);  //or overwrite original
  LogicalVector isNA = is_na(x);
  size_t i = 0;
  while(isNA[i] && i < x.size()) ++i;
  for(++i; i < x.size(); ++i) if(isNA[i]) x[i] = x[i-1];
  return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject fillNaC(RObject x) {
  RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(FNA, x);
}
)")
fillNaC(y)
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

Those functions can be used inside `lapply` to apply them on *all columns* of a `data.frame`.

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, fillNaC)
```

Other answers using Rcpp, specialized on a data type, look like the following but are updating also the input vector.

```
y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)

Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector fillNaCN(NumericVector x) {
  for(auto i = x.begin()+1; i < x.end(); ++i) if(*i != *i) *i = *(i-1);
  return x;
}")

fillNaCN(y)
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
y
# [1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

Benchmark

```
fillNaR <- function(y) {
  i <- which(is.na(y[-1]))
  j <- which(diff(c(-1L,i)) > 1)
  k <- diff(c(j, length(i) + 1))
  i <- rep(i[j], k)
  `[<-`(y, i + sequence(k), y[i])
}

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> FNA(const Vector<RTYPE> y) {
  auto x = clone(y);  //or overwrite original
  LogicalVector isNA = is_na(x);
  size_t i = 0;
  while(isNA[i] && i < x.size()) ++i;
  for(++i; i < x.size(); ++i) if(isNA[i]) x[i] = x[i-1];
  return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject fillNaC(RObject x) {
  RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(FNA, x);
}
)")

repeat.before <- function(x) {   # @Ruben
    ind = which(!is.na(x))
    if(is.na(x[1])) ind = c(1,ind)
    rep(x[ind], times = diff(c(ind, length(x) + 1) ))
}

RB2 <- function(x) {
  ind = which(c(TRUE, !is.na(x[-1])))
  rep(x[ind], diff(c(ind, length(x) + 1)))
}

MC <- function(y) { # @Montgomery Clift
  z  <- !is.na(y)  
  z  <- z | !cumsum(z)
  y[z][cumsum(z)]
}

MC2 <- function(y) {
  z <- c(TRUE, !is.na(y[-1]))
  y[z][cumsum(z)]
}

fill.NAs <- function(x) { # @Valentas
  is_na <- is.na(x)
  x[Reduce(function(i,j) if (is_na[j]) i else j, seq_len(length(x)), accumulate=T)]}

M <- alist(
fillNaR = fillNaR(y),
fillNaC = fillNaC(y),
repeat.before = repeat.before(y),
RB2 = RB2(y),
MC = MC(y),
MC2 = MC2(y),
fill.NAs = fill.NAs(y),
tidyr = tidyr::fill(data.frame(y), y)$y,
zoo = zoo::na.locf(y, na.rm=FALSE),
data.table = data.table::nafill(y, type = "locf"),
data.table2 = with(data.table::data.table(y)[, y := y[1], .(cumsum(!is.na(y)))], y),
imputeTS = imputeTS::na_locf(y, na_remaining = "keep"),
runner = runner::fill_run(y, FALSE),
vctrs = vctrs::vec_fill_missing(y, direction = "down"),
ave = ave(y, cumsum(!is.na(y)), FUN = \(x) x[1])
)
```

Result

```
n <- 1e5
set.seed(42); y <- rnorm(n); is.na(y) <- sample(seq_along(y), n/100)
bench::mark(exprs = M)  #1% NA
#   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 fillNaR       399.82µs   1.02ms    459.      3.56MB    31.9    230    16
# 2 fillNaC       672.85µs 883.74µs    976.      1.15MB    22.0    488    11
# 3 repeat.before   1.28ms    2.8ms    290.      7.57MB    58.0    145    29
# 4 RB2             1.93ms   3.66ms    229.      9.86MB    57.7    115    29
# 5 MC              1.01ms   1.98ms    289.      5.33MB    37.9    145    19
# 6 MC2            884.6µs   1.96ms    393.      6.09MB    53.5    198    27
# 7 fill.NAs       89.37ms   93.1ms     10.1     4.58MB    13.5      6     8
# 8 tidyr           8.42ms   11.3ms     86.3     1.55MB     5.89    44     3
# 9 zoo             1.83ms   3.19ms    216.      7.96MB    31.9    108    16
#10 data.table     73.91µs 259.71µs   2420.    797.38KB    36.0   1210    18
#11 data.table2    54.54ms  58.71ms     16.9     3.47MB     3.75     9     2
#12 imputeTS      623.69µs   1.07ms    494.      2.69MB    30.0    247    15
#13 runner          1.36ms   1.58ms    586.    783.79KB    10.0    293     5
#14 vctrs         149.98µs 317.14µs   1725.      1.53MB    54.0    863    27
#15 ave           137.87ms 149.25ms      6.53   14.77MB     8.17     4     5

set.seed(42); y <- rnorm(n); is.na(y) <- sample(seq_along(y), n/2)
bench::mark(exprs = M)  #50% NA
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 fillNaR         2.15ms   3.13ms    217.      7.92MB    59.7    109    30
# 2 fillNaC       949.22µs   1.09ms    728.      1.15MB    28.0    364    14
# 3 repeat.before   1.36ms   1.89ms    287.      4.77MB    49.6    185    32
# 4 RB2             1.64ms   2.44ms    347.      7.06MB    39.9    174    20
# 5 MC              1.48ms   1.92ms    443.      4.77MB    34.0    222    17
# 6 MC2             1.09ms   1.72ms    479.      5.53MB    45.9    240    23
# 7 fill.NAs       93.17ms 104.28ms      9.58    4.58MB     9.58     5     5
# 8 tidyr           7.09ms  10.07ms     96.7     1.55MB     3.95    49     2
# 9 zoo             1.62ms   2.28ms    344.      5.53MB    29.8    173    15
#10 data.table    389.69µs 484.81µs   1225.    797.38KB    14.0    613     7
#11 data.table2    27.46ms  29.32ms     33.4      3.1MB     3.93    17     2
#12 imputeTS        1.71ms    2.1ms    413.      3.44MB    25.9    207    13
#13 runner          1.62ms   1.75ms    535.    783.79KB     7.98   268     4
#14 vctrs         144.92µs 293.44µs   2045.      1.53MB    48.0   1023    24
#15 ave            66.38ms  71.61ms     14.0    10.78MB    10.5      8     6
```

Depending on how many NA's are filled up either `data.table::nafill` or `vctrs::vec_fill_missing` are the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

```
fill.NAs <- function(x) {is_na<-is.na(x); x[Reduce(function(i,j) if (is_na[j]) i else j, seq_len(length(x)), accumulate=T)]}

fill.NAs(c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA))

[1] NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

Reduce is a nice functional programming concept that may be useful for similar tasks. Unfortunately in R it is ~70 times slower than `repeat.before` in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this function. I do not know how fast or slow it is. But it does its job without having to use libraries.

```
replace_na_with_previous<-function (vector) {
        if (is.na(vector[1])) 
            vector[1] <- na.omit(vector)[1]
        for (i in 1:length(vector)) {
            if ((i - 1) > 0) {
                if (is.na(vector[i])) 
                    vector[i] <- vector[i - 1]
            }
        }
        return(vector)
    }
```

if you want to apply this function in a dataframe, if your dataframe is called df then simply

```
df[]<-lapply(df,replace_na_with_previous)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this here as this might be helpful for others with problems similar to the asked question.

The most recent `tidyverse` solution using the `vctrs` package can be compined with `mutate` to create a new column

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(vctrs)

as.data.frame(y) %>%
  mutate(y_filled = vec_fill_missing(y, direction = c("down")) )
```

Returns

```
   y  y_filled
1  NA       NA
2   2        2
3   2        2
4  NA        2
5  NA        2
6   3        3
7  NA        3
8   4        4
9  NA        4
10 NA        4
```

While changing the 'filling direction' to `'up'` results in:

```
    y  y_filled
1  NA        2
2   2        2
3   2        2
4  NA        3
5  NA        3
6   3        3
7  NA        4
8   4        4
9  NA       NA
10 NA       NA
```

Might wanna also try `"downup"` or `"updown"`

Please note that this solution is still in experimental life cycle so the syntax might change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my function `roll_na_fill()` which is optimised for data consisting of many groups.

##### Example benchmark

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")

library(timeplyr)
library(vctrs)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(imputeTS)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

x <- sample.int(10^2, 10^5, TRUE)
x[sample.int(10^5, round(10^5/3))] <- NA
groups <- sample.int(10^3, 10^5, TRUE)

dt <- data.table(x, groups)

### No groups

m1  <- microbenchmark(data.table = dt[, filled1 := data.table::nafill(x, type = "locf")][]$filled1,
                      vctrs = dt[, filled3 := vctrs::vec_fill_missing(x)][]$filled3,
                      zoo = dt[, filled4 := zoo::na.locf0(x)][]$filled4,
                      timeplyr = dt[, filled5 := .roll_na_fill(x)][]$filled5,
                      imputeTS = dt[, filled6 := na_locf(x, na_remaining = "keep")][]$filled6,
                      times = 20)
autoplot(m1)
```

[image]

```r
### With groups

m2 <- microbenchmark(data.table = dt[, filled1 := data.table::nafill(x, type = "locf"),
                            by = groups][]$filled1,
            vctrs = dt[, filled3 := vctrs::vec_fill_missing(x), by = groups][]$filled3,
            zoo = dt[, filled4 := zoo::na.locf0(x), by = groups][]$filled4,
            timeplyr1 = dt[, filled5 := .roll_na_fill(x), by = groups][]$filled5,
            timeplyr2 = dt[, filled7 := roll_na_fill(x, g = groups)][]$filled7,
            imputeTS = dt[, filled6 := na_locf(x, na_remaining = "keep"), 
                          by = groups][]$filled6,
            times = 20)
autoplot(m2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below:

```
nullIdx <- as.array(which(is.na(masterData$RequiredColumn)))
masterData$RequiredColumn[nullIdx] = masterData$RequiredColumn[nullIdx-1]
```

nullIdx gets the idx number where ever masterData$RequiredColumn has a Null/ NA value.
In the next line we replace it with the corresponding Idx-1 value,  i.e. the last good value before each NULL/ NA

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple consecutive missing values - `1 NA NA` turns into `1 1 NA`. Also, I think the `as.array()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, although I'm not sure whether it is more efficient than other suggestions.

```
rollForward <- function(x){
  curr <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (is.na(x[i])){
      x[i] <- curr
    }
    else{
      curr <- x[i]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, but a very concise and expandable answer for use with `library(data.table)` and therefore usable as `dt[,SomeVariable:= FunctionBellow, by = list(group)]`.

```
library(imputeTS)
y <- c(NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA)
y
[1] NA  2  2 NA NA  3 NA  4 NA NA
imputeTS::na_locf(imputeTS::na_locf(y,option = "nocb"),option="locf")
[1] 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```