# How to use grepl and ifelse to create a new column based on the first column of the dataframe

Tags: r, csv, if-statement, grepl

I am new to both R and SO and after figuring quite a few things in my dataset, I am kind of stuck on this new challenge. I am working on a .csv dataset and I am using r for datacleaning.

If you see, the first column label reads 'District/Subdistrict'. In that column, the District names start with a underscore and the sub district names are written as is. Now what I need to do is create a new column at the end, (column number 5) in my .csv with the label 'District'. I need to know how to use grepl and/or ifelse to populate that new column based on the first column as follows. I am going to use the example of the District name <_A>.

The new column should contain the values <_A> corresponding to the values of the District <_A> and values of Subdistricts under the District such as , ,  in the first column. Similarly, this should repeat for other districts such as the next District name <_E> and its subdistricts.

I know how to load the data in R and set the working directory etc. I just need specific help with the code for this output that I am looking for. Even some sort of a generic form would be helpful. Apologies for the shortcomings in this question.

Sample data:

```
    District/Subdistrict  X   Y   Z
           _A             10  12  13
            B             8   40  15
            C             21  22  23
            D             32  40  21
           _E             24  94  97
            F             56  72  12
            G             35  23  12
            H             54  23  17
```

Expected output

```
             District/Subdistrict  X   Y   Z   District
                   _A             10  12  13     _A
                    B             8   40  15     _A
                    C             21  22  23     _A
                    D             32  40  21     _A
                   _E             24  94  97     _E
                    F             56  72  12     _E
                    G             35  23  12     _E
                    H             54  23  17     _E
```

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including sample data and expected output directly _in the question_.

Comment: It's really not the mission of SO to start at the very beginning and teach you  how to do data entry and text processing with R . So what you do know how to do.  We also don't accept questions with data in the form of pictures. That would imply that you believe we should redo your data entry. Sorry Chaley.

Comment: maybe you should try something like `sub(".*(_)","\\1",data[,1])`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have included the same now. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `tidyverse` variant could help you.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Just for my purpose to get your data sample I create a tibble via `tribble()`. Because you already have your data as `data.frame` (I suppose) you can ignore it.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~`District/Subdistrict`, ~X,  ~Y,  ~Z,
                      "_A",                    10,  12,  13,
                      "B",                      8,  40,  15,
                      "C",                     21,  22,  23,
                      "D",                     32,  40,  21,
                      "_E",                    24,  94,  97,
                      "F",                     56,  72,  12,
                      "G",                     35,  23,  12,
                      "H",                     54,  23,  17)
```

Now the code that hopefully helps you:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(District = if_else(grepl("^_", `District/Subdistrict`), `District/Subdistrict`, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(District) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#       District/Subdistrict  X  Y  Z District
# 1                       _A 10 12 13       _A
# 2                        B  8 40 15       _A
# 3                        C 21 22 23       _A
# 4                        D 32 40 21       _A
# 5                       _E 24 94 97       _E
# 6                        F 56 72 12       _E
# 7                        G 35 23 12       _E
# 8                        H 54 23 17       _E
```

Comment: For `na.locf` see for example this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735681/9148552](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735681/9148552) to a similar problem

Comment: You don't need `zoo` for this task if you already load `tidyverse`, just use `tidyr::fill(Dis)`. You can also get rid of that `.$`. Hence, `df %>% mutate(Dis = if_else(grepl("^_", Dis.SubDis), Dis.SubDis, NA_character_)) %>% fill(Dis)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @tino for style correction, I adjusted my answer

Comment: @giovannotti Thank you!! But I am getting an error: `could not find function "mutate"`. I have installed tidyverse, dplyr and magrittr. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the error? Did you load the library `tidyverse`? You can explicitly call `dplyr::mutate()`, `tidyr::fill()` but there seems to be another problem.

Comment: @giovannotti the dataframe has 7406 elements in the 'District/Sub District' variable. How do I include all those in the `tibble::tribble()` command? I believe the problem is there.

Comment: You don't have to use `tribble`. It was just my way to create a data frame from your data sample above. I suppose your data is of class `data.frame`, then the code works fine. `mutate`and `fill` transform the `data.frame` additionaly into a "tibble". If you want to get your data.frame back, just add `as.data.frame()` at the end. I will update my post.

Comment: I think it is because you forgot backticks around District/Sub District. But is that the correct name of your column? Data frames do not allow slashes in column names so I guess it has to be another string.

Comment: @giovannotti yeah I was missing the initial backticks and I also figured that slashes don't work. Now the code works without any errors. But the 'District' column is still all empty.

Comment: Could you update your question post with a original print example of your data frame? For example the output of `head(<yourdataframe>)` or `dput(droplevels(<yourdataframe>))`? I can't reproduce your empty column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 rep(grep("_",dat[,1],value = T),table(cumsum(grepl("_",dat[,1]))))
[1] "_A" "_A" "_A" "_A" "_E" "_E" "_E" "_E"
```

or even:

```
cut(m<-cumsum(s<-grepl("_",dat[,1])),length(unique(m)),dat[s,1])
[1] _A _A _A _A _E _E _E _E
Levels: _A _E
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea via `ave`,

```
with(df, ave(District.Subdistrict, cumsum(grepl('_', District.Subdistrict)), 
                                                           FUN = function(i) head(i, 1)))
#[1] _A _A _A _A _E _E _E _E
#Levels: _A _E B C D F G H
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much. However, the new column was created as a separate data frame. Is there a way to have it in the same data frame?