# R - how to fill NA's between two corresponding ID's in a dataframe

Tags: r, data-munging

I am trying to take the the following dataset and convert it to the second. Basically, I'm trying to fill in the NA's between each ID with that ID.

Each ID corresponds to two time stamps, which I've joined in to a larger date_time column. For purposes of reproduce-ability, it's too computationally expensive to do a sql between join (the date_time column is very large) or even to take the original dataset and create the time stamps between each id and then join it in (I have too many ID's to do this). I've successfully completed both those methods and it just takes too much time for the amount of data I have. I'm hoping to manipulate the data with this data set. It seems like such a simple thing, but it's really got me stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Current data set:

```
             date_time     id
                <dttm>  <dbl>
 1 2017-01-30 08:00:00     NA
 2 2017-01-30 08:00:01     NA
 3 2017-01-30 08:00:02     1
 4 2017-01-30 08:00:03     NA
 5 2017-01-30 08:00:04     NA
 6 2017-01-30 08:00:05     NA
 7 2017-01-30 08:00:06     NA
 8 2017-01-30 08:00:07     1
 9 2017-01-30 08:00:08     NA
10 2017-01-30 08:00:09     NA
11 2017-01-30 08:00:10     2
12 2017-01-30 08:00:11     NA
13 2017-01-30 08:00:12     NA
14 2017-01-30 08:00:13     NA
15 2017-01-30 08:00:14     2
16 2017-01-30 08:00:15     NA
17 2017-01-30 08:00:16     3
18 2017-01-30 08:00:17     NA
19 2017-01-30 08:00:18     3
20 2017-01-30 08:00:19     NA
```

Desired dataset:

```
            date_time     id
                <dttm>  <dbl>
 1 2017-01-30 08:00:00     NA
 2 2017-01-30 08:00:01     NA
 3 2017-01-30 08:00:02     1
 4 2017-01-30 08:00:03     1
 5 2017-01-30 08:00:04     1
 6 2017-01-30 08:00:05     1
 7 2017-01-30 08:00:06     1
 8 2017-01-30 08:00:07     1
 9 2017-01-30 08:00:08     NA
10 2017-01-30 08:00:09     NA
11 2017-01-30 08:00:10     2
12 2017-01-30 08:00:11     2
13 2017-01-30 08:00:12     2
14 2017-01-30 08:00:13     2
15 2017-01-30 08:00:14     2
16 2017-01-30 08:00:15     NA
17 2017-01-30 08:00:16     3
18 2017-01-30 08:00:17     3
19 2017-01-30 08:00:18     3
20 2017-01-30 08:00:19     NA
```

dput() date:

```
structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1485781200, 1485781201, 
1485781202, 1485781203, 1485781204, 1485781205, 1485781206, 1485781207, 
1485781208, 1485781209, 1485781210, 1485781211, 1485781212, 1485781213, 
1485781214, 1485781215, 1485781216, 1485781217, 1485781218, 1485781219
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), trx_id = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, 1, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 1, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, 2, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 2, 
NA_real_, 3, NA_real_, 3, NA_real_)), .Names = c("date_time", 
"trx_id"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: could you use `dput` so that we can copy the example dataframe?

Comment: Use function `na.locf` from package `zoo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

Comment: @Pdubbs I added the output from dput(). I'm new to including reproducible examples, so let me know if what I did wasn't right.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried na.locf, but it fills the NA's after the ID's (so if there was a `c(3, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4)` it would convert it to `c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)`, which I don't want). I want the data to be `c(3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 4)`.

Comment: OK, I will retract my close as dupe vote. I had misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution could be using `fill` function from `tidyr`. The approach is simple. First create 2 columns one each for `prev` and `next` values. Use `fill` to populate missing values in both columns.

Now, for rows which has same value in both `prev_val` and `next_val` the value should be updated with `prev_val` (that means those missing values are between same number)

```
df <-  read.table(text = "sl date_time, value
1 '2017-01-30 08:00:00'     NA
2 '2017-01-30 08:00:01'     NA
3 '2017-01-30 08:00:02'     1
4 '2017-01-30 08:00:03'     NA
5 '2017-01-30 08:00:04'     NA
6 '2017-01-30 08:00:05'     NA
7 '2017-01-30 08:00:06'     NA
8 '2017-01-30 08:00:07'     1
9 '2017-01-30 08:00:08'     NA
10 '2017-01-30 08:00:09'     NA
11 '2017-01-30 08:00:10'     2
12 '2017-01-30 08:00:11'     NA
13 '2017-01-30 08:00:12'     NA
14 '2017-01-30 08:00:13'     NA
15 '2017-01-30 08:00:14'     2
16 '2017-01-30 08:00:15'     NA
17 '2017-01-30 08:00:16'     3
18 '2017-01-30 08:00:17'     NA
19 '2017-01-30 08:00:18'     3
20 '2017-01-30 08:00:19'     NA", header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)

#use fill to find missing values
df %>%
  mutate(prev_val = (value), next_val = (value)) %>%
  fill(prev_val, .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(next_val, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(prev_val == next_val, prev_val, value )) %>%
  select(-prev_val, -next_val)

Result:
   sl          date_time. value
1   1 2017-01-30 08:00:00    NA
2   2 2017-01-30 08:00:01    NA
3   3 2017-01-30 08:00:02     1
4   4 2017-01-30 08:00:03     1
5   5 2017-01-30 08:00:04     1
6   6 2017-01-30 08:00:05     1
7   7 2017-01-30 08:00:06     1
8   8 2017-01-30 08:00:07     1
9   9 2017-01-30 08:00:08    NA
10 10 2017-01-30 08:00:09    NA
11 11 2017-01-30 08:00:10     2
12 12 2017-01-30 08:00:11     2
13 13 2017-01-30 08:00:12     2
14 14 2017-01-30 08:00:13     2
15 15 2017-01-30 08:00:14     2
16 16 2017-01-30 08:00:15    NA
17 17 2017-01-30 08:00:16     3
18 18 2017-01-30 08:00:17     3
19 19 2017-01-30 08:00:18     3
20 20 2017-01-30 08:00:19    NA
```

Comment: This worked great and was highly efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `base R` option.  We `split` the sequence of rows of the dataset with 'trx_id' (the one OP showed as input data), get the sequence (`seq`), `stack` it to two column dataset and assign the 'trx_id' to 'ind' column of 'd1' based on the 'values' as index from 'd1'

```
d1 <- stack(lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$trx_id), function(x) seq(x[1], x[2])))
df1$trx_id[d1$values] <- d1$ind
df1$trx_id
#[1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3 NA
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this on my full data set. It says `Error in seq.default(x[1], x[2]) : 'to' must be a finite number`. I'm working to figure it out, but it does work on the example code I've given.

Comment: @jstauss  That's interesting.  Can you check the output of `split(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$trx_id)`

Answer (score 4):

A non tidyr approach, where x is your id column:

```
x <- c(NA,NA, 1,NA,NA,1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA,2, NA, 3,NA, NA,3,NA)

timestamps <- paste(unique(x)[!is.na(unique(x))], collapse = "|")

timestamps <- grep(timestamps, x)
timestamps <- matrix(timestamps, ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)

xmatrix <- apply(timestamps, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(i) {
  y <- x[i[1]:i[2]]
  y[is.na(y)] <- x[i][1]
  x[i[1]:i[2]] <- y 
  return(x)
})

(x <- apply(xmatrix, 1,FUN = function(z) {

  ifelse(all(is.na(z)), NA, max(z, na.rm=TRUE))
  }))

##  [1] NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA NA  2  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3  3 NA
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for this. Trying to keep it in the tidyverse, but this worked great.