# Double for loop with NA in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a couple of questions with my R script. I have a database with many series which have NA and numeric values. I would like to replace the NA by a 0 from the moment we have a numeric value but keep the NA if the serie is not started.

As we see below, for example in the second column I would like to keep the 2 first NA but replace the fourth by 0.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0yf3.png)

There is my script, but it doesn't work

[my actual script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf4p5.png)

It would be very kind to have some suggestions

Many thanks

ER

Comment: Your script is an image... Can you post code instead?

Comment: Relavant, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value

Answer (score 1):

In case you, or anyone else, want to avoid for loops:

```
# example dataset
df = data.frame(x1 = c(23,NA,NA,35),
                x2 = c(NA,NA,45,NA),
                x3 = c(4,34,NA,5))

# function to replace NAs not in the beginning of vector with 0
f = function(x) { x[is.na(x) & cumsum(!is.na(x)) != 0] = 0; x }

# apply function and save as dataframe
data.frame(sapply(df, f))

#   x1 x2 x3
# 1 23 NA  4
# 2  0 NA 34
# 3  0 45  0
# 4 35  0  5
```

Or using `tidyverse` and the same function `f`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% map_df(f)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#     x1    x2    x3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   23.   NA     4.
# 2    0.   NA    34.
# 3    0.   45.    0.
# 4   35.    0.    5.
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is your dataset:

```
ORIGINAL_DATA <- data.frame(X1 = c(23, NA, NA, 35), 
                            X2 = c(NA, NA, 45, NA), 
                            X3 = c(4, 34, NA, 5))
```

This could probably work:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(ORIGINAL_DATA)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(ORIGINAL_DATA)) {
    if(!is.na(ORIGINAL_DATA[j, i])) {
      ORIGINAL_DATA[c(j:nrow(ORIGINAL_DATA)), i] <- ifelse(is.na(ORIGINAL_DATA[c(j:nrow(ORIGINAL_DATA)), i]), 0, ORIGINAL_DATA[c(j:nrow(ORIGINAL_DATA)), i])

      # To end this for-loop
      j <- nrow(ORIGINAL_DATA)
    }
  }
}
```