# How to replace values and words using ifelse / lag / mutate in the same function?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data similar to these.

```
v1 <- c("Fail", 20, 30, "Out", NA, 32, 33, 10)
v2 <- c(10, NA, NA, "Out", "Fail", 34, 35, 30)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
```

I need to transform this data frame as well. So that the `'words'` or `NA` are the information immediately preceding, or if there is no previous information, I need to pick up the information later.

[image]

How can I actually do this using modern programming in `R`? I'm doing something like this, according to [this link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/116317_e6922e81e72e4e3f83995485ce686c14.html#/6).

```
df <- df %>% mutate(v11 = ifelse(v1 %in% "Fail", lag(),
                     ifelse(v1 %in% "Out", lag()),
                     ifelse(is.na(v1) %in% lag(), v1)))
```

Comment: why is `v1[5]` which is `NA` becomes 32 instead of 30?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

Comment: @MikeH. It seems to be, but it's not 100% the same. Even here came good and new answers. Even have words on the `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
   replace(array(grepl("\\D",as.matrix(df)),dim(df)),NA)%>%
   mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.x)))%>%
   fill(v1:v2,.direction ="down")%>%
   fill(v1:v2,.direction = "up")
  v1 v2
1 20 10
2 20 10
3 30 10
4 30 10
5 30 10
6 32 34
7 33 35
8 10 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution from `zoo` ,`na.locf`

```
df[which(df=="Fail" | df=='Out')]='NA'
zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(df),fromLast=T)
  v1 v2
1 20 10
2 20 10
3 30 10
4 30 10
5 30 10
6 32 34
7 33 35
8 10 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `fill`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
     mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>% 
     fill(v1, v2) %>%
     fill(v1, .direction = 'up')
#   v1 v2
#1 20 10
#2 20 10
#3 30 10
#4 30 10
#5 30 10
#6 32 34
#7 33 35
#8 10 30
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the non-numeric strings to NA using `read.table` giving `df0` and then use `na.approx`.  This gives a matrix.  If you want a data frame use `as.data.frame` on the result.

```
library(zoo)

df0 <- read.table(text = paste(df$v1, df$v2), na.strings = c("NA", "Out", "Fail"))
na.approx(df0, method = "constant", rule = 2)
```

giving:

```
     V1 V2
[1,] 20 10
[2,] 20 10
[3,] 30 10
[4,] 30 10
[5,] 30 10
[6,] 32 34
[7,] 33 35
[8,] 10 30
```

If desired, we could express this using magrittr like this:

```
library(matrittr)
library(zoo)

df %$%
  paste(v1, v2) %>%
  read.table(text = ., na.strings = c("NA", "Out", "Fail")) %>%
  na.approx(method = "constant", rule = 2)
```