# Dygraph with multiple series at different time intervals

Tags: r, time-series, dygraphs

I have 2 sets of time series with different time intervals which I am attempting to show in a single dygraph plot;

- Stage (river level) and Modelled Stage - 5 or 15 minute interval
- Rainfall and Forecast Rainfall - 3 hourly interval

I would like the stage set to be a line chart and rainfall to appear as a step plot similar to below.

[image: Old static version on the plot]

My issue is that, as far as I can see, you *must* cbind your timeseries together in order to create a multi-series dygraph. Cbind fills in 'missing' points with NA causing my graph to appear with isolated points of rainfall like so

[image: Dygraph version displays rainfall as instantaneous points]

Is there any way to overplot in dygraph without combining everything into 1 time series object? Alternatively does anybody have any clever methods for filling in NAs during a cbind? I have a rather inelegant bit of code to fill in NAs after the cbind at the moment...

---

**Example code for second plot**

```
stage <- zoo(sample(1:100, 154, replace=TRUE), seq(as.POSIXct("2018-08-23"), as.POSIXct("2018-08-31"), by = 4500))
rain <- zoo(sample(1:100, 154, replace=TRUE), seq(as.POSIXct("2018-08-23"), as.POSIXct("2018-08-31"), by = 54000))

eventData <- cbind(stage, rain)

dygraph(eventData, main = "Sitename") %>% 
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE, colors = colour, drawGrid = F) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Stage", valueRange = c(0, maxStage+maxStage*.2), independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label = "Rainfall ", valueRange = c(0, maxRain+maxRain*.5), independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("Stage", axis=('y')) %>%
  dySeries("Rainfall", axis=('y2'), stepPlot = T, fillGraph = T) %>%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.locf` function to fill the missing rows.

In your example:

```
stage <- zoo(sample(1:100, 154, replace=TRUE), seq(as.POSIXct("2018-08-23"), as.POSIXct("2018-08-31"), by = 4500))
rain <- zoo(sample(1:100, 154, replace=TRUE), seq(as.POSIXct("2018-08-23"), as.POSIXct("2018-08-31"), by = 54000))

eventData <- cbind(stage, rain)
head(eventData)

                    stage rain
2018-08-23 00:00:00    85   61
2018-08-23 01:15:00    71   NA
2018-08-23 02:30:00    10   NA
2018-08-23 03:45:00    16   NA
2018-08-23 05:00:00    31   NA
2018-08-23 06:15:00    92   NA

# fill NAs with na.locf

eventData <- na.locf(eventData)
head(eventData)

                    stage rain
2018-08-23 00:00:00    85   61
2018-08-23 01:15:00    71   61
2018-08-23 02:30:00    10   61
2018-08-23 03:45:00    16   61
2018-08-23 05:00:00    31   61
2018-08-23 06:15:00    92   61
```

This can be plotted the way you want it:

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(eventData, main = "Sitename") %>% 
  dyOptions(drawGrid = F) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Stage", independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label = "Rainfall ", independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("stage", axis=('y')) %>%
  dySeries("rain", axis=('y2'), stepPlot = T, fillGraph = T)
```

[image]

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value) for a deeper discussion about filling NAs.