# Get index from last previous non-NA value

Tags: r, tidyverse, na

I have this vector

```
set.seed(234)
x <- sample(c(rep(NA,3),1:5))
x
[1]  3  5 NA  1  4 NA NA  2
```

For each `NA`, I want the index (or value) of the last preceeding non-`NA` value. That is, for the first `NA`, the last previous non-`NA` has the index 2. For the next two `NA`, their last previous non-`NA` has index 5:

```
[1]  NA  NA 2  NA  NA 5 5  NA
```

Base `R` or `tidyverse` would be ok. I tried combinations of `lag`, `lead`, `rle`, `gl` & `coalesce`, but all without success. For instance this which is pretty near, but still wrong.

```
a <- rle(is.na(x))
rep(1:length(a$lengths), a$lengths)
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the values you want are correct?  The way I'm reading "last non-NA" value would imply that the string you want is -- NA NA 5 NA NA 4 4 NA.  In the third position, wouldn't 5 be the last non-na value?

Comment: @Pawel yes, indeces or values are both ok.

Comment: @Pawel, I think he means he wants to make for each NA the index for the last non-NA value that preceded it.

Comment: Yep.  Sorry.  Re-read it and it make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using base R

```
y=1:length(x)
y[is.na(x)]=0
y=cummax(y)
y[!is.na(x)]=NA

y
[1] NA NA  2 NA NA  5  5 NA
```

squeeze to one_line from [**Henrik**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340274/get-index-from-last-non-na-value/53340530#comment93560201_53340530)

```
replace(cummax(seq_along(x) * !is.na(x)), !is.na(x), NA)
```

Comment: As a oneliner `replace(cummax(seq_along(x) * !is.na(x)), !is.na(x), NA)`

Comment: @Henrik that is great, would you mind I adding your one_liner ?

Comment: I added a link to Henrik's comment you included in the answer. if you mind my editing, say so and I will retract the edit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas no worry , I just do not know how to add the link , thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the values with the `tidyr` function `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
fill(as.data.frame(x),x)[is.na(x),]
#[1] 5 4 4
```

Comment: this! `tibble(x) %>%  fill(x)` . Thanks for the function.

Comment: @Jimbou If you 'only' want to replace the `NA` with previous non-`NA` (as e.g. `fill` does), see [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)