# Trying to fill in missing data with a specific year and to fill it in a sequence.

Tags: r, dplyr

```
rookie_1_team$year[1:5] <- "2018"
rookie_1_team$year[6:10] <- "2017"
rookie_1_team$year[11:15] <- "2016"
rookie_1_team$year[16:20] <- "2015"
rookie_1_team$year[21:25] <- "2014"
```

Is there a way to write this in a for loop or a function instead of just manually putting it in all the way to 2000.  Or maybe an apply?

So it would be a sequence of 5 before going down a year to then go to the next year like 2017. Then go through 5 again filling out 2017 then go down one again to 2016.

Any hints or help would be great.  Still very new to R.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, it's better(best) to add data to your question using `dput(head(mydata,20))`.

Comment: `rookie_1_team$year[1:5]` is a vector, i.e. has no dimensions. Read `help("rownames<-")`

Comment: if the *missing* entries are `NA` you can use `zoo::na.locf`   , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value , but we can't tell if this is the case from a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
 df <- data.frame(
   year=c("2018","","","","2017","",""),
   x=c(1:7))
 library(tidyverse)
 df %>% 
   mutate(year=as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
   fill(year)
  year x
1 2018 1
2 2018 2
3 2018 3
4 2018 4
5 2017 5
6 2017 6
7 2017 7
```