# Replacing NAs with values in the previous row for each group

Tags: r, na

In `df` i would like to replace the NA values with the previous non-NA value for each id

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
purchase<-c(20,NA,NA,10,NA,NA,5)
df<-data.frame(id,purchase)

 id purchase
  1       20
  1       NA
  1       NA
  1       10
  2       NA
  2       NA
  2        5
```

The output should ideally look like:

```
id purchase
  1       20
  1       20
  1       20
  1       10
  2       NA
  2       NA
  2        5
```

I am aware of [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value), but it does not do it per group. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve it with a combination of `group_by()` from `dplyr` and `fill()` from `tidyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways (so far), all utilizing `zoo::na.locf` by *per group*. One thing to note is that you *need* `na.rm=FALSE`, otherwise `zoo::na.locf` may return a shortened vector (as is the case where `id` is 2).

## Base R

```r
do.call("rbind.data.frame",
        by(df, df$id, function(x) transform(x, purchase = zoo::na.locf(purchase, na.rm=FALSE))))
#     id purchase
# 1.1  1       20
# 1.2  1       20
# 1.3  1       20
# 1.4  1       10
# 2.5  2       NA
# 2.6  2       NA
# 2.7  2        5
```

## `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(purchase = zoo::na.locf(purchase, na.rm = FALSE))
```

## `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, purchase := zoo::na.locf(purchase, na.rm = FALSE), by = "id" ]
```

Comment: I think all is covered in linked post.