# Can't find a way to carry the last good value down

Tags: r, zoo

This is a bit hard to describe but I'll give it a shot.
Suppose I have the following zoo object:

```
a <- read.zoo(data.frame(date=as.Date('2011-1-1') + 0:59, closest.idx=c(rep(1,20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20)), is.good=c(rep(1,20), rep(1,20), rep(0, 20)), val=c(rep(.2, 6), rep(.3, 14), rep(.4, 6), rep(.5, 14), rep(.6, 6), rep(.7, 14))), FUN = as.Date)
           closest.idx is.good val
2011-01-01          1       1 0.2
2011-01-02          1       1 0.2
2011-01-03          1       1 0.2
2011-01-04          1       1 0.2
2011-01-05          1       1 0.2
2011-01-06          1       1 0.2
2011-01-07          1       1 0.3
2011-01-08          1       1 0.3
2011-01-09          1       1 0.3
2011-01-10          1       1 0.3
...
```

I would like to carry down the last good "val". Here are the rules:

1. The first 6 rows of each group should not be changed no matter what value is.good has
2. The next rows are changed if is.good = 0. If is.good = 0 the val is changed to the last.good.val)
3. The last good val is one where is.good = 1 and which appears on the 7th row or greater of that group

> NOTE #1: Don't assume there will be a total of 20 rows in a group - it could be any number
>
> NOTE #2: You can assume that the first 6 rows of each group shouldn't be touched

So in this example,

```
2011-01-01 - 2011-01-06 will have a val of 0.2 (is.good = 1, < 6 rows into group so not last.good.val)
2011-01-07 - 2011-01-20 will have a val of 0.3 (is.good = 1, last.good.val = 0.3)
2011-01-21 - 2011-01-26 will have a val of 0.4 (is.good = 1, last.good.val = 0.3, < 6 rows into group so not last.good.val)
2011-01-27 - 2011-02-09 will have a val of 0.5 (is.good = 1, last.good.val = 0.5)
2011-02-10 - 2011-02-15 will have a val of 0.6 (b/c they are < 6 rows into the group so aren't affected)
2011-02-16 - 2011-03-01 will have a val of 0.5 (b/c 0.5 was the last good value and is.good = 0 in this group)
```

So I expect my output to look like this:

```
           closestIdx is.good val
2011-01-01          1       1 0.2
2011-01-02          1       1 0.2
2011-01-03          1       1 0.2
2011-01-04          1       1 0.2
2011-01-05          1       1 0.2
2011-01-06          1       1 0.2
2011-01-07          1       1 0.3
2011-01-08          1       1 0.3
2011-01-09          1       1 0.3
...
2011-01-21          2       1 0.4
2011-01-22          2       1 0.4
2011-01-23          2       1 0.4
2011-01-24          2       1 0.4
2011-01-25          2       1 0.4
2011-01-26          2       1 0.4
2011-01-27          2       1 0.5
2011-01-28          2       1 0.5
2011-01-29          2       1 0.5
2011-01-30          2       1 0.5
2011-01-31          2       1 0.5
...
2011-02-10          3       0 0.6
2011-02-11          3       0 0.6
2011-02-12          3       0 0.6
2011-02-13          3       0 0.6
2011-02-14          3       0 0.6
2011-02-15          3       0 0.6
2011-02-16          3       0 0.5    <- notice these changed to last good value
2011-02-17          3       0 0.5
2011-02-18          3       0 0.5
...
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution but other packages would be
> interesting to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several approaches that each do essentially the same:

- Add a column `val_tofill` replacing all non-good vals by `NA`'s
- Use one of many available methods to forward fill `val_tofill`, see  e.g. [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)
- Overwrite the `val` column by `val_tofill` whenever the row number is not one of the first six of the group (grouped by `closest.idx`)

**Initial data**

```
a <- data.frame(
    date=as.Date('2011-1-1') + 0:59, 
    closest.idx=c(rep(1,20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20)), 
    is.good=c(rep(1,20), rep(1,20), rep(0, 20)), 
    val=c(rep(.2, 6), rep(.3, 14), rep(.4, 6), rep(.5, 14), rep(.6, 6), rep(.7, 14))
)
```

**base + zoo::na.locf**

```
a$val_tofill <- zoo::na.locf(ifelse(a$is.good > 0, a$val, NA))
a$val <- unlist(
    by(a, INDICES = a$closest.idx,
        FUN = function(x) ifelse(seq_len(nrow(x)) < 7, x$val, x$val_tofill)
    )
)
a$val_tofill <- NULL
```

**dplyr + tidyr::fill**

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate(a, val_tofill = ifelse(is.good > 0, val, NA)) %>%
    fill(val_tofill, .direction = "down") %>%
    group_by(closest.idx) %>%
    mutate(val = ifelse(row_number() < 7, val, val_tofill)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-val_tofill)
```

**data.table + zoo::na.locf**

```
library(data.table)

a <- setDT(a)
a[, val_tofill := zoo::na.locf(ifelse(is.good > 0, val, NA))][,
    val := ifelse(seq_len(.N) < 7, val, val_tofill),
    by = closest.idx
]
a$val_tofill <- NULL
```