# R Function that replaces NAs with lagged values

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lag, fillna

I am trying to write a function that replaces the missing values of selected variables in a data frame with their lagged values (I am using a one obs. lag) in R. I have successfully written the following for loop to do this:

```
testdata <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:10), 
                       x2 = c(4, 3, NA, 7, 8, NA, 9, NA, 10, 11), 
                       x3 = c(4, 3, NA, 7, 8, NA, 9, NA, NA, 11),
                       x4 = c("a", NA, NA, "d", "e", NA, "f", NA, "g", NA))

for (j in 2:4){
  for (i in 1:10){
    if(is.na(testdata[i, j])){
      testdata[i, j] <- testdata[i - 1, j]
    }}}
```

The for loop works fine, however will I generalize this code and write it in a function the function create an empty list. The function that I have written is as follows:

```
fill_null <- function(df, columns, rows){
  for (j in columns){
    for(i in rows){
      if(is.na(df[i, j])){
        df[i,j] <- df[i - 1, j]
      } else{
        df[i, j] <- df[i, j]
      }}}}
```

When I run this function using the following code:

```
newdf <- fill_null(testdata, 2:4, 1:10)
str(newdf)
```

I get the following output:

```
> str(newdf)
 NULL
```

I am wondering why this for loop will work when it is not called in a function but stops working once it is written into a function. I am also wondering if there is an easy way to fix this issue because I have to fill NA with lagged values for several different data frames.

Comment: Put `return(df)` at the end of your function.

Comment: You may also be interested in the functions `zoo::na.locf` (for a single column) or `tidyr::fill` (for a whole data frame), which do this with more features, and more efficiently. See, for example, [this FAQ on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7735647/903061). Your function does the same thing as `tidyr::fill(testdata)`

Comment: Stability is a big advantage of using well tested functions. For example, I think your function will throw an out-of-bounds error if there are `NA` values in the first row of the data.

Comment: I'd also add that R has a a few good ways to apply a function to certain columns of a data frame. Rather that hardcode that in your function, I'd suggest writing a simpler function that works on a single vector. This function is more flexible than what you have, and you can apply it to columns using usual R methods like `for` or `lapply`, e.g., `testdata[columns] = lapply(testdata[columns], simple_fill_null)`. Or if you really want the column interface, write a wrapper that does that `lapply`. Keeping your functions small and modular makes them easier to debug and more flexible to use.

Answer (score 0):

In R, functions will (unless told otherwise) return the last value generated. In your function, you may think that the last value is `df` however it is actually the `for` loop. As per the documentation in `?"for"`, `for` loops return `NULL` as their value. An easy way to demonstrate this is `test <- for(x in 1:3){x}; test` which returns `NULL`.

To fix this, you can either end your function with `return(df)` or simply `df`.

To address the heart of your issue however, the dplyr package has a `lag` function which you may find helpful (`testdata$j <- ifelse(is.na(testdata$j), lag(testdata$j), testdata$j))`)