# Filling in missing value in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID  year    fcmstat secmstat  mstat
138 4   1998    NA          NA      1
139 4   1999    NA          NA      1
140 4   2000    NA          NA      1
141 4   2001    NA          NA      1
142 4   2002    NA          NA      1
143 4   2003    2           NA      2
144 4   2004    NA          NA      NA
145 4   2005    NA          NA      NA
146 4   2006    NA          3       3
147 4   2007    NA          NA     NA

375 19  2001    NA          NA      2
376 19  2002    6           NA      6
377 19  2003    NA          NA      NA
378 19  2004    NA          5       5
379 19  2005    NA          NA      NA
380 19  2006    NA          NA      1
```

`fcmstat`: type of first marital status change

`secmstat`: type of second marital status change

first marital status, for ID 4(19), `fsmstat` was changed in 2003(2002) and second marital status `secmstat` was changed in 2006(2004). So, for ID 4, in 2004 and 2005 marital status was same as `fcmstat` of 2003 and for ID 19, 2003's `mstat` should be same as `fcmstat` of 2002.

I want to fill in t he last column as follows:

```
    ID  year    fcmstat secmstat  mstat
138 4   1998    NA          NA      1
139 4   1999    NA          NA      1
140 4   2000    NA          NA      1
141 4   2001    NA          NA      1
142 4   2002    NA          NA      1
143 4   2003    2           NA      2
144 4   2004    NA          NA      2
145 4   2005    NA          NA      2
146 4   2006    NA          3       3
147 4   2007    NA          NA     NA

375 19  2001    NA          NA      2
376 19  2002    6           NA      6
377 19  2003    NA          NA      6
378 19  2004    NA          5       5
379 19  2005    NA          NA      NA
380 19  2006    NA          NA      1
```

Also, before any first change, the `mstat`should be same as before. Consider the following case.

```
        ID  year    fcmstat secmstat    mstat
1171    61  1978    NA      NA           0
1172    61  1979    NA      NA           0
1173    61  1980    NA      NA           0
1174    61  1981    NA      NA           0
1175    61  1982    NA      NA           0
1176    61  1983    NA      NA          NA
1177    61  1984    NA      NA          NA
1178    61  1985    1       NA           1
1179    61  1986    NA      NA           1
1180    61  1987    NA      NA           1
```

the first change was in 1985. So, the missing `mstat` in 1984 and 1983 should be same as `mstat` of 1982. SO for this case, my desired output is:

```
       ID   year    fcmstat secmstat    mstat
1171    61  1978    NA      NA           0
1172    61  1979    NA      NA           0
1173    61  1980    NA      NA           0
1174    61  1981    NA      NA           0
1175    61  1982    NA      NA           0
1176    61  1983    NA      NA           0
1177    61  1984    NA      NA           0
1178    61  1985    1       NA           1
1179    61  1986    NA      NA           1
1180    61  1987    NA      NA           1
```

As suggested by Schilker the code `df$mstat_updated<-na.locf(df$mstat)` gives the following:

```
    ID  year    fcmstat secmstat  mstat mstat_updated
138 4   1998    NA          NA      1     1
139 4   1999    NA          NA      1     1
140 4   2000    NA          NA      1     1
141 4   2001    NA          NA      1     1
142 4   2002    NA          NA      1     1
143 4   2003    2           NA      2     2 
144 4   2004    NA          NA      NA     2   
145 4   2005    NA          NA      NA     2
146 4   2006    NA          3       3     3 
147 4   2007    NA          NA     NA     3
148 4   2008    NA          NA     NA     3
```

However, I do want to fill in mstat for 2004 and 2005 but not in 2007 and 2008. I want to fill in NA's only between first marstat change, `fcmstat` and second marstat, `secmstat` change.

Comment: Looks like all the values needed are already in `mstat`. I recommend reading the help page for [zoo::na.locf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/na.locf)

Comment: I have also provided my desired outcome. That's why you see in the 2nd  and the 4th tables, NA's are replaced with values. Thanks so much for your reference to zoo::na.locf .

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment this a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

```
library(zoo)

df<-data.frame(ID=c('4','4','4','4'),
              year=c(2003,2004,2005,2006),
              mstat=c(2,NA,NA,3))
df$mstat<-na.locf(df$mstat)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This is close but not exactly what I want. I have added further details in my original post. Any help will be much appreciated.