# Repeat row in a column of a data table

Tags: r

I have a data table which includes `NA`s in some cells as below.
Datatable:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEisZ.jpg)
However, I want to repeat 1st row in the column called "Category" to the following two rows written "NA" without any change in other columns which are "Numeric" and "Numeric.null". Same thing for 4th row in Category, repeat it to 5th and 6th rows but no change in other columns.
New:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU4ZQ.jpg)

I'm just learning R programming. I have tried rep function. But I couldn't do. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
          fill(Category)
df1
#  Category Numeric Numeric.null
#1        A       1            1
#2        A       2            2
#3        A       3            4
#4        D       4            7
#5        D       5            6
#6        D       6            8
#7        E       7           11
```

---

Or using `data.table` with `na.locf0`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, Category := na.locf0(Category)][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("A", NA, NA, "D", NA, NA, "E"), Numeric = 1:7, 
    Numeric.null = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 11L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Is there any solution with data.table function?