# Variance over time with two dataframes in R

Tags: r, variance, panel-data

I have two dataframes. df1 is a dataframe where every row is a score that someone gives.

df1

```
title <- c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y")
day <- c(0,2,2,4,1,1,3,3,4)
score <- c(7,7,6,4,8,1,7,1,5)
df1 = data.frame(title,day,score)
```

df2 is title-day formatted panel dataset in long format with a lot of variables. I'm looking for a way to mutate the variance score on day x and the variance score over time (i.e. variance of the score(s) on day x and all the previous scores that are there).

It should look like this:

```
title <- c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y")
day <- c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
variance_day_x <- c(0,0,0.5,0,0,0,24.5,0,12,0)
variance_cumulative <- c(0,0,0.3333,0.3333,2,0,24.5,24.5,14.25,10.8)
df2 <- data.frame(title,day,variance_day_x,variance_cumulative)
```

As you can see I need to mutate 2 variables out of df1 into df2. The variance per day is the first variable, where variance = 0 when there is 0 or 1 score available on that day because there is nothing to calculate. The second variable is cumulative variance where the variance needs to be updated every time there are new scores available.

Hope this explained my problem well enough. I'm stuck at this moment, hope you guys can help!

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: I already did. See df2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you could try something like this. First `group_by` `title` and use a custom cumulative variance function that can be called from `mutate`. The daily variance is computed after grouping by both `title` and `day`. `complete` will fill in missing days, and `fill` will carry forward the cumulative variance for those missing days. You can replace the `NA` with zero if you would like with `replace_na`.

```
library(tidyverse)

cumvar <- function(x)  {
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) var(x[1:i]))
}

df1 %>%
  group_by(title) %>%
  mutate(cvar = cumvar(score)) %>%
  group_by(title, day) %>%
  summarise(variance_day_x = var(score),
            variance_cumulative = last(cvar)) %>%
  complete(title, day = 0:4) %>%
  fill(variance_cumulative, .direction = "down")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   title [2]
   title   day variance_day_x variance_cumulative
   <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>               <dbl>
 1 x         0           NA                NA    
 2 x         1           NA                NA    
 3 x         2            0.5               0.333
 4 x         3           NA                 0.333
 5 x         4           NA                 2    
 6 y         0           NA                NA    
 7 y         1           24.5              24.5  
 8 y         2           NA                24.5  
 9 y         3           18                14.2  
10 y         4           NA                10.8
```

Comment: Really liked this simple solution. Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy Base R solution:

```
df_variances <- cbind(df1,  data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df1, df1$title),
       function(x){
        variance_cumulative <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i){
          z <- var(x$score[1:i]) 
          }
        )
        variance_day_x <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(j){
          q <- var(x$score[(j-1):j])
          }
        )
       variance_df <- data.frame(variance_day_x = variance_day_x,
                                 variance_cumulative = variance_cumulative)
    }
  )
), row.names =  NULL))

df_clean <- replace(df_variances, is.na(df_variances), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution. I also use a custom `cumvar` function. Furthermore I use [*@Ruben*'s great `repeat_last` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810615/6574038) to fill up `NA`s with last known values.

This solution bases mainly on `ave`, which applies a function on a variable, grouped by other variables. Since the days are not complete, we can `merge` the original data to a complete data set with all `unique` titles and days. Before we calculate the `var`iances, we calculate the cumulative variances; the idea is to select later the "newer" value per day using `length`. Finally we delete the dupes, then it's done.

```
cumvar <- function(x) sapply(1:length(x), function(i) {var(x[1:i])})
df1$vari.cum <- with(df1, ave(score, title, FUN=cumvar))
compl <- expand.grid(title=unique(df1$title), day=unique(df1$day))
dfx <- merge(compl, df1, all.x= TRUE)
dfx$vari.cum <- with(dfx, ave(vari.cum, title, FUN=repeat_last))
res <- within(dfx, {
  vari.day <- ave(score, title, day, FUN=var)
  vari.cum <- ave(vari.cum, title, day, FUN=function(x) x[length(x)])
})
res <- res[!duplicated(res[c("title", "day")]), c(1:2, 5:4)]
res
#   title day vari.day   vari.cum
# 1      x   0       NA         NA
# 2      x   1       NA         NA
# 3      x   2      0.5  0.3333333
# 5      x   3       NA  0.3333333
# 6      x   4       NA  2.0000000
# 7      y   0       NA         NA
# 8      y   1     24.5 24.5000000
# 10     y   2       NA 24.5000000
# 11     y   3     18.0 14.2500000
# 13     y   4       NA 10.8000000
```