# Find rows with NA between 0s and 1s

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I want to identify rows that contains NA, and is between a zero and a one. Consider this data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0))

# DT
# a
# 1:  0
# 2: NA
# 3: NA
# 4:  0
# 5: NA
# 6:  1
# 7:  1
# 8: NA
# 9:  0
# 10: NA
# 11:  1
# 12: NA
# 13: NA
# 14: NA
# 15:  0
# 16:  1
# 17:  1
# 18:  0
# 19: NA
# 20:  0
```

How to identify row no. 5, 8, 10 and 12:14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `approx`

```
DT[,b := approx((1:.N)[!is.na(a)],na.omit(a),1:.N)$y]
```

and then apply

```
DT[, which(is.na(a) & b>0 & b<1)]
```

or

```
DT[, which(is.na(a) & between(b, 0, 1, FALSE))]
```

which gives

```
[1]  5  8 10 12 13 14
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Guess you could make it a bit more simple to omit is.na(DT[,a]) &, so it is only which(DT[,b]>0 & DT[,b]<1), as all that is !is.na(a) is always 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

The begin of the NA-sequences can calculated so:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- data.table(a = c(0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0))

r <- DT[, rle(is.na(a))]
R <- data.table(r$values, r$lengths, start=c(1, 1+head(cumsum(r$lengths), -1)))

i <- R[(V1), start]
j <- R[(V1), start+V2-1]
i[(DT[i-1, a] + DT[j+1, a])==1]
# result: [1]  5  8 10 12
```

Answer (score 1):

The `zoo` package and its `na.locf()` function could help you as described by Dirk Eddelbuettel in here: [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value).

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

DT <- data.table(a = c(0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0))

non_nas <- DT[!is.na(a), a]
successor <- c(non_nas[-1], 0)
diff <- abs(non_nas - successor)
DT[!is.na(a), diff:=diff]
```

This will give you a data table as follows:

```
     a diff
 1:  0    0
 2: NA   NA
 3: NA   NA
 4:  0    1
 5: NA   NA
 6:  1    0
 7:  1    1
 8: NA   NA
 9:  0    1
10: NA   NA
11:  1    1
12: NA   NA
13: NA   NA
14: NA   NA
15:  0    1
16:  1    0
17:  1    1
18:  0    0
19: NA   NA
20:  0    0
```

The idea here is that every '1' in the diff column tells you that the value in 'a' is going to change after the NAs below.

Now you want to get rid of the NAs in the 'diff' column. For clarity, we put the result into the new column 'b'. This is where the `zoo` package comes into play:

```
DT[, b:=na.locf(diff)]
```

This results in

```
     a diff b
 1:  0    0 0
 2: NA   NA 0
 3: NA   NA 0
 4:  0    1 1
 5: NA   NA 1
 6:  1    0 0
 7:  1    1 1
 8: NA   NA 1
 9:  0    1 1
10: NA   NA 1
11:  1    1 1
12: NA   NA 1
13: NA   NA 1
14: NA   NA 1
15:  0    1 1
16:  1    0 0
17:  1    1 1
18:  0    0 0
19: NA   NA 0
20:  0    0 0
```

Eventually

```
DT[is.na(a) & b == 1, which = TRUE]
```

will give you:

```
[1]  5  8 10 12 13 14
```