# R Problem Using cumsum in data.table to Forward Fill

Tags: r, data.table, cumsum

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt = data.table( grp=round(runif(10)), val=c(runif(4), NA, runif(4), NA) )
dt
```

Output is:

```
    grp        val
 1:   0 0.95683335
 2:   1 0.45333416
 3:   0 0.67757064
 4:   1 0.57263340
 5:   1         NA
 6:   0 0.10292468
 7:   1 0.89982497
 8:   1 0.24608773
 9:   1 0.04205953
10:   0         NA
```

I'd like to fill the `val` with the previous non-NA value of `val`.

The SO question "Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value" has [an amazing SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45595607), which I do not fully comprehend. Nonetheless, I tried:

```
dt[ , val2 := val[1], .(grp, cumsum(!is.na(val))) ]
dt
```

Output is:

```
    grp        val       val2
 1:   0 0.95683335 0.95683335
 2:   1 0.45333416 0.45333416
 3:   0 0.67757064 0.67757064
 4:   1 0.57263340 0.57263340
 5:   1         NA 0.57263340
 6:   0 0.10292468 0.10292468
 7:   1 0.89982497 0.89982497
 8:   1 0.24608773 0.24608773
 9:   1 0.04205953 0.04205953
10:   0         NA         NA
```

This almost works (it correctly filled in row 5). Why does the 10th row of `dt` still have an `NA` value a `val2` instead of `0.10292468` (the previous non-NA value for `grp == 0`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `nafill` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, val2 := nafill(val, type = 'locf')]
```

-output

```
dt
#    grp        val       val2
# 1:   0 0.95683335 0.95683335
# 2:   1 0.45333416 0.45333416
# 3:   0 0.67757064 0.67757064
# 4:   1 0.57263340 0.57263340
# 5:   1         NA 0.57263340
# 6:   0 0.10292468 0.10292468
# 7:   1 0.89982497 0.89982497
# 8:   1 0.24608773 0.24608773
# 9:   1 0.04205953 0.04205953
#10:   0         NA 0.04205953
```

---

The reason it is `NA` in the OP's output is based on the grouping

```
dt[, cumsum(!is.na(val))]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8
```

last two elements are grouped as 8, where as the 'grp' last element is 0, so there is only one element that matches and if we use `val[1]` which `NA` and thus we got the `NA`

It can be more clear if we check the `.GRP` with `by` argument

```
dt[, .GRP, by = .(grp1 = cumsum(!is.na(val)), grp)]
#      grp1 grp GRP
#1:    1   0   1
#2:    2   1   2
#3:    3   0   3
#4:    4   1   4
#5:    5   0   5
#6:    6   1   6
#7:    7   1   7
#8:    8   1   8
#9:    8   0   9  # -> only a single element for group 9
```

Thus, `val[1]` returns the `NA` element

However, if we do an `order` on 'grp' and then create the new group with `cumsum`, the adjacent elements are different, thus there are more than one element per group

Comment: Thanks! I kind of like the other SO answer I just added a little more, only because it is more general and I can specify any value that I want to replace, not just NA.

Comment: @TMo I answered the reason why you are getting NA in the edit

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your answer to make sense to me. There is still one part left unexplained. Once you can explain why val[1] results in NA, then I can mark the response as the best answer.

Comment: @TMo the reason I specified in the post i.e. the last two grouping from `cumsum` is a single value, but the last value in 'grp' is 0, so there is only a single element for the last NA and thus when you do `val[1]` it is the `NA` that gets replaced.  However, if you do an `order(grp)` and then apply the `cumsum` on the new ordered data, the adjacent elements are different now, creating a new grouping

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I just noticed that the SO answer I referred to first ordered `dt` by `grp`. I tried that and it worked.

```
dt = data.table( grp=round(runif(10)), val=c(runif(4), NA, runif(4), NA) )
dt = dt[ order(grp) , ] ## seems to be critical step
dt[ , val2 := val[1], .(grp, cumsum(!is.na(val))) ]
dt
```

Output is:

```
    grp        val       val2
 1:   0 0.95683335 0.95683335
 2:   0 0.67757064 0.67757064
 3:   0 0.10292468 0.10292468
 4:   0         NA 0.10292468
 5:   1 0.45333416 0.45333416
 6:   1 0.57263340 0.57263340
 7:   1         NA 0.57263340
 8:   1 0.89982497 0.89982497
 9:   1 0.24608773 0.24608773
10:   1 0.04205953 0.04205953
```