# subset datatable to replace NAs with latest non-NA value

Tags: r, arrays, data.table

I m trying to use the solution here:
[Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

to a large data table, but can't manage to work out.

My datatable `childs` is at the link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17MwTpk0l9vX-A3gUXlPUoszLZ8OchdIb/view?usp=sharing).
I want to create a column `pop1` that takes value from `pop` when `value` is missing. The tricky bit is to pass the right group, which I am unable to.

if I subset first:

```
child_sub<- childs[ sector_number=='3.B.2.1.1' & meastype== 'NRATE']
```

and then

```
childs1 <- child_sub[, pop1:=pop[1], .( cumsum(!is.na(value)) )]
```

it works, in the sense that it gives `pop1` for the year 2019 the value of `pop` of 2018, that is 1591.251.
however, if I try:

`childs1 <- childs[, pop1:=pop[1], .( party, sector_number, meastype, cumsum(!is.na(value)) )]`,
it doesn't assign the correct `pop` (i.e.the `pop` from the same `meastype`, previous year), and I don't understant why...

I also tried with:

```
childs1 <- childs[is.na(value), pop1:=setnafill(pop, type = "locf")]
```

which throws error straight away.

any help appreciated

Comment: I think setnafill is what you want

Comment: you should provide example code to reproduce, then I would provide code that answers your question

Comment: Hi thanks. The data are with the link, where it says ' here'

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution in case someone will be reading this in the future. I realised that the solution proposed here [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value), and that I wanted to replicate, does't work when there are two consecutive NA values. In that case there is no `pop[1]` and returns zero. The solution is to sort before the line `childs[, pop1:=pop[1], .( sector_number, meastype, cumsum(!is.na(value)) )]`:

```
setkey(childs, sector_number, meastype)
childs[, pop1:=pop[1], .(sector_number, meastype, cumsum(!is.na(value)) )]
```

with this, it returns the desired outcome.