# Replace NAs with previous values using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with some datasets in R and, despite being able to solve my problem with base R, I'm really curious to know how to solve it with data.table, as I really made it the hard way.

I have the following data table:

```
head(assets)
date   XPTO ACME
1: 2011-05-31 669.1328 50.25
2: 2011-06-01 674.6444 49.77
3: 2011-06-02 657.3590 49.85
4: 2011-06-03 NA 49.43
5: 2011-06-06 667.0009 49.05
6: 2011-06-07 NA 48.96
```

I need to replace every NA with the value right before it, like in a for loop (I'll skip the for statement to make it short):

```
ifelse(is.na(assets[i])==TRUE, assets[i]<-assets[i-1], assets[i]<-assets[i])
```

Is there a way to do such a task with data.table syntax?

Comment: What if you have two `NA` in a row?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45595607/9463489

Comment: Please, see the `nafill()` or the `setnafill()` functions in the `data.table` package as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764998/3817004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.locf()`.

```
assets[,XPTO := zoo::na.locf(XPTO)]
```

To answer jblood94 question, this function fills all NAs with the latest Non-NA value.

Answer (score 0):

Would the `fillNAgaps` function listed [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Filling_in_NAs_with_last_non-NA_value/) work? You can just change the `firstBack` argument as appropriate. If you have two `NA`s in a row, I believe it'll put the same one again, if that's what you're looking for.