# Join data.frame with repeated lines in R

Tags: r, join

I have two dataframes. One is quality with different dates throughout the year of collection points at station `st`. The other is the land use of each `st` season for that year.

> Example
>
> library(dplyr)
>
> ```
> water_df=read.table(text="st  Date    OD  pH  DBO
> A 01/07/2005  8   6.3 3
> A 02/06/2005  7   6.2 2.2
> A 01/01/2005  7.3 6.5 3.1
> A 03/05/2006  6   6.3 4
> A 09/08/2006  6.8 7.1 1.1
> A 12/12/2006  7.3 8.1 2.9
> B 02/07/2005  6.8 5.4 2.6
> B 03/06/2005  6.0 5.3 1.9
> B 02/01/2005  6.2 5.5 2.6
> B 04/05/2006  5.1 5.4 3.4
> B 10/08/2006  5.8 6.0 0.9
> B 13/12/2006  6.2 6.9 2.5
> C 20/12/2006  6.5 7.2 2.6
> C 27/12/2006  6.8 7.6 2.7
> C 03/01/2007  7.2 8.0 2.9
> C 10/01/2007  7.5 8.4 3.0
> C 17/01/2007  7.9 8.8 3.1
> C 24/01/2007  8.3 9.2 3.3
> C 31/01/2007  8.7 9.7 3.5
> C 07/02/2007  9.2 10.2    3.6", sep="", header=TRUE)%>%as.data.frame()
>
>
>
> land_df=read.table(text = "st year    Veg Water   Soil    Crop    Grass
> A 2005    100 200 80  130 70
> B 2006    98  180 84  132 86
> C 2007    93  175 79  127 106", sep="", header = TRUE)%>%as.data.frame()
> ```

I would like to add to the quality data.frame the land use values of that station even if for the same station `st` is repeated.

[image]

I tried some things but it didn't work

```
#I tryed cbind
join_df<-cbind(water_df, land_df)

#I tryed
library(purrr)
joind_df2<-purrr::reduce(water_df, land_df)
```

Comment: `merge(water_df, land_df, by = "st", all.x = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation it commonly called a "join" or "merge". You need columns to join on, which means we need to extract the year from your date, and then it's  a `left_join` command. [See this FAQ for more information about joining data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300618/903061).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

water_df %>%
  mutate(year = year(dmy(Date))) %>%
  left_join(land_df, by = c("st", "year"))
#    st       Date  OD   pH DBO year Veg Water Soil Crop Grass
# 1   A 01/07/2005 8.0  6.3 3.0 2005 100   200   80  130    70
# 2   A 02/06/2005 7.0  6.2 2.2 2005 100   200   80  130    70
# 3   A 01/01/2005 7.3  6.5 3.1 2005 100   200   80  130    70
# 4   A 03/05/2006 6.0  6.3 4.0 2006  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 5   A 09/08/2006 6.8  7.1 1.1 2006  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 6   A 12/12/2006 7.3  8.1 2.9 2006  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 7   B 02/07/2005 6.8  5.4 2.6 2005  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 8   B 03/06/2005 6.0  5.3 1.9 2005  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 9   B 02/01/2005 6.2  5.5 2.6 2005  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 10  B 04/05/2006 5.1  5.4 3.4 2006  98   180   84  132    86
# 11  B 10/08/2006 5.8  6.0 0.9 2006  98   180   84  132    86
# 12  B 13/12/2006 6.2  6.9 2.5 2006  98   180   84  132    86
# 13  C 20/12/2006 6.5  7.2 2.6 2006  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 14  C 27/12/2006 6.8  7.6 2.7 2006  NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
# 15  C 03/01/2007 7.2  8.0 2.9 2007  93   175   79  127   106
# 16  C 10/01/2007 7.5  8.4 3.0 2007  93   175   79  127   106
# 17  C 17/01/2007 7.9  8.8 3.1 2007  93   175   79  127   106
# 18  C 24/01/2007 8.3  9.2 3.3 2007  93   175   79  127   106
# 19  C 31/01/2007 8.7  9.7 3.5 2007  93   175   79  127   106
# 20  C 07/02/2007 9.2 10.2 3.6 2007  93   175   79  127   106
```

There's some missing values where your `land_df` didn't have observations for a particular station in a particular year. Have a look at `?tidyr::fill` and [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7735647/903061) if you want to fill those in with, e.g., the previous observation.