# flatten a unbalanced(ragged) hierarchy

Tags: r, pivot, hierarchy, flatten, ragged

So I have a .csv file that displays a ragged hierarchy vertically. The indent_nbr indicates the levels each item is at in the hierarchy, with 0 being the top parent.

```
   item indent_nbr
1     A          0
2     B          1
3     C          2
4     D          3
5     E          4
6     F          4
7     G          4
8     H          5
9     I          5
10    J          5
11    K          5
12    L          4
13    M          5
14    N          5
15    O          5
16    P          5
17    Q          3
18    R          4
```

I want to flatten this hierarchy to look like this matrix.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  NA  
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "F"  NA  
 [3,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "H" 
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "I" 
 [5,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "J" 
 [6,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "K" 
 [7,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "M" 
 [8,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "N" 
 [9,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "O" 
[10,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "P" 
[11,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "Q"  "R"  NA
```

Can someone help me with this?

please note that I'm limited to using the following packages:
base, boot, class, cluster, codetools, compiler datasets, foreign, graphics, grDevices, grid, Kernsmooth, lattice, MASS, Matrix, methods, mgcv, nlme, nnet, parallel, rpart, spatial, splines, stats, stats4, survival, tcltk, tools, translations, utils

Comment: Your specification appears incomplete. Why, as just one example, is there no output row with  F in level 4 and  H at level 5?

Comment: @Limey - Thank you for standardizing my question into the right format. I'm not a R coder. I'm an accountant. I was able to do this transformation in Excel using macro (to find the indentation number) and formulas, with the correct template design.

Comment: @Limey - However, the real hierarchy has over 100K items (child and parent combined). It starts to kill my laptop. The IT owner of the hierarchy is not doing a good job cleaning it or helping finance users formatting it so it's easier to read and/or investigate. that's why i m trying every venue I'm aware of that might be able to help, including chatgpt. And yes there's no value after E or F in column 6, because they designed the hierarchy to be unbalanced

Answer (score 2):

To turn hierarchical data into a matrix, we could first make groups `g` according to where the hierarchy changes. Then, we create an array `a` sized according to these groups and levels. Next, we place the items in this array based on where they fall in the hierarchy.
This way we get the first complete sequence and end points of the following, thus leaving NAs which can be filled column-wise with last non-NA using *Ruben*'s [`repeat_last`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810615/6574038), so no extra packages are needed. However this overwrites true NAs which we store beforehand in `na_ind` and recover afterwards.

```
> hrr2mat <- \(dat) {
+   g <- c(0, cumsum(diff(dat$indent_nbr) != 1))
+   a <- array(dim=c(length(table(g)), length(table(dat$indent_nbr))))
+   a[cbind(g + 1, dat$indent_nbr + 1)] <- dat$item
+   na <- apply(!is.na(a), 1, \(x) max(cumsum(diff(x) >= 0) + 1)) + 1
+   w <- which(na <= ncol(a))
+   na_ind <- t(mapply(cbind, w, lapply(na[w], `:`, ncol(a))))
+   a <- apply(a, 2, repeat_last)
+   a[na_ind] <- NA
+   return(a)
+ }
> hrr2mat(dat)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  NA  
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "F"  NA  
 [3,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "H" 
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "I" 
 [5,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "J" 
 [6,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "K" 
 [7,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "M" 
 [8,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "N" 
 [9,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "O" 
[10,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "L"  "P" 
[11,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "Q"  "R"  NA
```

Not sure how it scales but might be a start.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(item = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"), indent_nbr = c(0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```